# Pagination is not updated

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to update pagination. but for some reason it doesn't work here is my code

```
// it contains a list
var _ordersState: Flow<PagingData<AllOrder>> =
        getActiveOrderInterface.getListOrder().cachedIn(viewModelScope)


// when a user cancels an order, I receive a canceled order in combine (I change the found order), but the pagination is not updated.
fun cancelOrder(id: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val answer = getActiveOrderInterface.cancelOrder(id)
                    .collect {
                        _ordersStateCancel = flow { OnChange(it) }
                    }

                Log.d("MyTag", "cancelOrder $answer")


                _ordersState = combine(
                    _ordersStateCancel,
                    _ordersState) { i,t -> t.map { item ->
                    if (item.productId == i.value.productId){
                        item.copy(status = i.value.status)
                    }else {
                        item
                    }
                }
                }
```

help please...

ViewModel
class OrdersViewModel @Inject constructor(private val getActiveOrderInterface: GetActiveOrderInterface) :
ViewModel() {

```
// список всех заказов
var _ordersState: Flow<PagingData<AllOrder>> =
    getActiveOrderInterface.getListOrder().cachedIn(viewModelScope)


var stateFlowAllOrder = MutableStateFlow(0) // количество всех заказов
val stateFlowActiveOrder = MutableStateFlow(0) // количество активных заказов
```

//    var _ordersStateCancel = MutableStateFlow(OnChange(AllOrder())) // отменённы ордер
lateinit var _ordersStateCancel : Flow<OnChange>
var _ordersStateCancelExeption = MutableStateFlow(String()) // ошибка при отмене ордера

```
var positionСlickOrder = 0 // позиция заказа который был отменён
var oldOrder = AllOrder() // старый ордер



fun cancelOrder(id: String) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val answer = getActiveOrderInterface.cancelOrder(id)
                .collect {
                    _ordersStateCancel = flow { OnChange(it) }
                }

            Log.d("MyTag", "cancelOrder $answer")


            _ordersState = combine(
                _ordersStateCancel,
                _ordersState) { i,t -> t.map { item ->
                if (item.productId == i.value.productId){
                    item.copy(status = i.value.status)
                }else {
                    item
                }
            }
            }


        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("MyTag", "Except $e")
            _ordersStateCancelExeption.value = e.message.toString()
        }
    }
}

override fun onCleared() {
    viewModelScope.cancel()
}

class OnChange<T>(val value: T)
```

}

My fragment
class AllOrdersFragment : Fragment() {

```
private lateinit var binding: FragmentAllOrdersBinding
private lateinit var mainLoadStateHolder: DefaultLoadStateAdapter.Holder
private val viewModel: OrdersViewModel by activityViewModels()

private val allOrdersAdapter by lazy {
    AllOrderAdapter { order, position ->
        viewModel.positionСlickOrder = position
        viewModel.cancelOrder(order.id!!)
        viewModel.oldOrder = order
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = FragmentAllOrdersBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding.containerState.state = ProgressContainer.State.Loading

    setupUsersList()

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel._ordersState.collectLatest {
            allOrdersAdapter.submitData(it)
        }
    }

    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch {
        allOrdersAdapter.addLoadStateListener  {
                viewModel.stateFlowAllOrder.value = allOrdersAdapter.itemCount
        }
    }
    

    lifecycleScope.launch {
        viewModel._ordersStateCancelExeption.collectLatest {exeption ->
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Exeption: $exeption",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    stateAdapter(binding)

}

private fun stateAdapter(binding: FragmentAllOrdersBinding){
    allOrdersAdapter.addLoadStateListener { state ->

        binding.containerState.state = when (state.source.refresh) {
            is LoadState.Error -> {
                ProgressContainer.State.Notice("Ошибка")
            }
            is LoadState.Loading -> {
                ProgressContainer.State.Loading
            }
            is LoadState.NotLoading -> {
                if (allOrdersAdapter.itemCount == 0) {
                    ProgressContainer.State.Notice("Пустота")
                } else {
                    ProgressContainer.State.Success
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

private fun setupUsersList() {

    val tryAgainAction: TryAgainActionAllOrder = { allOrdersAdapter.retry() }

    val footerAdapter = AllOrderStateAdapter(tryAgainAction)

    val adapterWithLoadState = allOrdersAdapter.withLoadStateFooter(footerAdapter)

    binding.recyclerViewAllOrders.apply {
        layoutManager =
            LinearLayoutManager(requireContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        adapter = adapterWithLoadState

    }
    (binding.recyclerViewAllOrders.itemAnimator as? DefaultItemAnimator)?.supportsChangeAnimations = false

    mainLoadStateHolder = DefaultLoadStateAdapter.Holder(
        binding.loadStateView,
        binding.swipeRefreshLayout,
        tryAgainAction
    )
}
```

}

```
 // My adapter
class AllOrderAdapter(private var onItemClicked: ((product: AllOrder,position:Int) -> Unit)) :
PagingDataAdapter<AllOrder, AllOrderAdapter.ProductViewHolder>(DiffUtilCallBack()) {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder =
    ProductViewHolder(
        OrderFragmentBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bind(getItem(position))
}

inner class ProductViewHolder(
    private val itemBinding: OrderFragmentBinding,
) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemBinding.root) {

    fun bind(order: AllOrder?) = with(itemBinding) {
        textOrder.text = order?.createdAt
        textStatus.text = order?.status
        textSize.text = order?.productSize
        textdata.text = order?.etd
        textaddress.text = order?.deliveryAddress
        imageProduct.load(order?.productPreview!!)

        prBarCancel.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        imageCancel.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        imageCancel.setOnClickListener {
            val menu = PopupMenu(itemBinding.root.context,imageCancel)
            menu.inflate(R.menu.menu_order)
            menu.show()
            menu.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                if (item.itemId == R.id.cancel){
                    prBarCancel.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    imageCancel.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    onItemClicked(order,absoluteAdapterPosition)
                }
               return@setOnMenuItemClickListener true
            }
        }
    }

}


class DiffUtilCallBack : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<AllOrder>() {

    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: AllOrder, newItem: AllOrder): Boolean =
        oldItem.id == newItem.id

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: AllOrder, newItem: AllOrder): Boolean =
        oldItem == newItem
}
```

}